# Dynamic suppression of EntityNotFoundException in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, persistence

The following method executes a simple query via [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) to retrieve some custom `Entity` records from a database, given their unique IDs:

```
  public List<Entity> getEntity(Collection<Long> ids) {
    Session session = null;
    String sqlQuery =
      "SELECT entities.* FROM entities WHERE entities.id IN :ids";
    try {
      session = createSession();
      NativeQuery<Entity> query = session.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery)
        .addEntity(Entity.class)
          .setParameter("ids", ids);
      List<Entity> entities = query.list();
      return entities;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error(e);
      return null;
    } finally {
      if (session != null) {
        session.close();
      }
    }
  }
```

The code above seems to work as expected if the list of IDs supplied can be found in the database, but if any of the given IDs does not correspond to an existing record, the following exception is thrown:

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists
```

To suppress this exception statically (i.e., at compile time), the following annotation can be used in the `Entity` class:

```
@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
```

However, this approach is not an option if, for instance, the `Entity` class definition cannot be modified by client code.

Is there any way to suppress the exception dynamically (i.e., at runtime), e.g. on a per-query basis?

Comment: You are not using JPA but Hibernate native as I can see. If you use JPA query.getResultList() you will get an empty list only getSingleResult throws this exception

Comment: Correct, I have modified the post to reflect that. I will try getResultList().

Comment: But you havent modified the post to reflect that. It says JPA, and executes a JPA query ... and tags `jpa`. Kindly update it

Comment: The reference to `JPA` is valid, since `Hibernate` is an implementation of it. Anyway, the important thing here is that the `getResultList()` method still throws an exception for the cases described above, as `list()` does. Thanks.